# It seems that markdown preview and marp preview are in conflict

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown, preview, marp

I have installed the extension marp in VSCode. I want to see a slide preview, but it seems that markdown preview and marp preview are in conflict.
The preview display will be in pdf format, not in slide format.
Do I have to remove the markdown preview setting somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

solved.

When I selected Marp from the extension (Ctrl + Shift + X), it said "Reload required", so when I ran it, two preview icons appeared.

[image: left]

The icon on the left was a traditional markdown preview, but the icon on the right is displayed in slide format.

[image: right]

Thank you,